# Debug Julia v.0.6

Tags: debugging, julia, atom-editor

I have cloned a [repository](https://github.com/XiaojingGeorgeZhang/OBCA/tree/master/AutonomousParking) tested in Julia 0.5 and 0.6. I was previously using the newest Julia version (v.1.0.5) along with JuliaPro and Atom, which allowed me to debug and setting breakpoints easily. I have downloaded JuliaPro-0.6.4.1 but when I open the Atom editor I no longer have the options to debug or set breakpoints and I would like to know the best way to debug older versions of Julia, in my case Julia v.0.5 or v.0.6

Answer (score 4):

Julia 0.4 and maybe 0.5 can use Gallium.jl in theory.
There never was a debugger that worked for julia 0.6.
The modern Debugger.jl was made for 1.0+

I suggest using `println` debugging.