# Writing a simple tool for debuging julia 0.6

Tags: julia

There seems to be no easy-to-use debugger for julia 0.6 and so I tried to construct a simple `println` debugger as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59487287/debug-julia-v-0-6). The following code is a module that provides `@out` macro for writing expressions and their values into a file:

```
module debug
using DataStructures: OrderedDict

import JSON

function fn_print_dict(file, d)
  print(file, JSON.json(d,2))
end

function println_alltypes(file_to_write, eval_relevant_symbol, typeof_eval_relevant_symbol)
  
  if typeof_eval_relevant_symbol <: Dict
      fn_print_dict(file_to_write, eval_relevant_symbol)
  elseif typeof_eval_relevant_symbol <: AbstractArray || typeof_eval_relevant_symbol <: Set
      itr_collection_counter = 1
      dict_collection = OrderedDict()
      for item in eval_relevant_symbol
          dict_collection[itr_collection_counter] = item
          itr_collection_counter += 1
      end
      println_alltypes(file_to_write, dict_collection, Dict)
  else
      println(file_to_write, eval_relevant_symbol)
  end
  println(file_to_write)
end

export @out
macro out(relevant_symbols...)
  return esc(quote
  file_to_write_str = joinpath(homedir(), "output.txt")
  if !isdefined(current_module(),:debug_counter_int)
      debug_counter_int = 0
  end
      debug_counter_int += 1
      if debug_counter_int == 1
          open(file_to_write_str, "w") do file_to_write
              println(file_to_write)
          end
      end
      open(file_to_write_str, "a") do file_to_write
          println(file_to_write, "===================================")
      end
      for relevant_symbol in $relevant_symbols
          relevant_symbol_str = string(relevant_symbol)
          eval_relevant_symbol = eval(relevant_symbol)
          typeof_eval_relevant_symbol = typeof(eval_relevant_symbol)
          open(file_to_write_str, "a") do file_to_write
              println(file_to_write, "[$relevant_symbol_str]", " ($typeof_eval_relevant_symbol):")
              $println_alltypes(file_to_write, eval_relevant_symbol, typeof_eval_relevant_symbol)
          end
      end
  end)
end

end
```

For example,

```
julia> using debug

julia> a = [4, 5, Dict("a"=>44, "b"=>55)]
3-element Array{Any,1}:
 4                     
 5                     
  Dict("b"=>55,"a"=>44)

julia> @out 2+3

julia> @out a

julia> @out [a, a]

julia>
```

Will write the following content into `output.txt`:

```
===================================
[2 + 3] (Int64):
5

===================================
[a] (Array{Any,1}):
{
  "1": 4,
  "2": 5,
  "3": {
    "b": 55,
    "a": 44
  }
}


===================================
[[a, a]] (Array{Array{Any,1},1}):
{
  "1": [
    4,
    5,
    {
      "b": 55,
      "a": 44
    }
  ],
  "2": [
    4,
    5,
    {
      "b": 55,
      "a": 44
    }
  ]
}
```

The issue is that `@out` will raise an error when used in a function such as

```
function fn(y)
       @out y
       end
fn (generic function with 1 method)
```

I appreciate any help in fixing this issue or proposing an alternative approach. I know that `eval` should not be used in a macro, but I'm not sure what would be the alternative here.

Comment: 0.6 is rather ancient now. Unless you have a very good reason to use it, avoid it.

Comment: @phipsgabler Unfortunately I have to maintain (an later uplift) several thousand lines of code written in 0.6. Because I'm new to the project, it's hard to debug without any tool!

Comment: @rasul First, use 0.7 to run the code and upgrade the code to 1.0 according to all the errors and warnings (0.7 is the same as 1.0 except it shows how to fix each thing). And then you can directly run on 1.7 and use the latest tools

Answer (score 4):

I don't have quite enough metaprogramming experience to debug your macro easily, but as a stopgap I might suggest the built-in `@show` macro, which should do most of what you want, except it'll print the results to stdout rather than to file (but you should be able to just redirect to a file when running at the command line if that's something you need).

As the comments have suggested, Julia 0.6 is indeed ancient by now. Given your task of upgrading a large Julia 0.6 codebase, I can heavily second @jling's suggestion of running on Julia 0.7, which is equivalent to 0.6 except with deprecations to warn you about all the things you will need to change to run on `1.x`.